# How to make online user become out in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.3

I have an admin account and user acount so
I want to make an online user become out and deny all navigation immediately from my admin account when i set $user->active to 0:

```
$user->active = 0;
```

Comment: Users have soft-deletion on by default, so why not just `$user->delete()` and `$user->restore()` if you change your mind later?

Comment: I won't delete any user just make him out from system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use a middleware :

step 1: in terminal

```
php artisan make:middleware ActiveCompt
```

Step 2 set the middleware  :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Auth;
use Closure;

class ActiveCompt
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()){
            if ($request->user()->statut == 1) {
                return redirect('logout');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

step 3 : defining the route Of. in karnel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
.
.
.
'ActiveCompt' => \App\Http\Middleware\ActiveCompt::class,
];
```

step 4 : calling the middleware ActiveCompt from the constructors

```
$this->middleware('ActiveCompt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to logout the user once the status changed to inactive?

If this is the case you can do

```
public function updateUserStatus(){

  $user = Auth::user();
  $user->active = false;
  $user->save();
  Auth::logout();

  return redirect("/home");
}
```